# What type of functions map a simply connected set onto a simply connected set

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

As the question title states, in what cases can I say that a bijective continuous function $f(z): \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ maps all simply connected sets $A\in\mathbb{C}$ to a simply connected set $B = \{f(x), x\in A\}$?

Comment: I edited the question, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every continuous bijection $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a homeomorphism, by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).  So, for any $A\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism $A\to f(A)$, and in particular $A$ is simply connected iff $f(A)$ is simply connected.